# Why the first-degree Laplace operator is a vector not the sum of the derivative $x$ and $y$ components?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Why the second-degree Laplace operator is the sum of the $x$ and $y$ components

$$\nabla^2 f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$$

but the first-degree Laplace operator is a vector of $x$ and $y$ components?

$$\nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$

instead of just

$$\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Comment: There's no such thing as “the first-degree Laplace operator”. $\nabla f = (f_x,f_y)$ is the *gradient* and $\nabla \cdot f = f_x + f_y$ is the *divergence*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to derive the Laplacian (Laplace operator) is to view $\nabla^2$ as $\nabla\cdot \nabla$, where $\nabla=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right).$

With this view , we have

\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot \nabla&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}
\end{align}

as inner product. Note that this means, in some sense, taking Laplacian on a function $f$ is the same as taking gradient first and then taking divergence.